# Swift - A function with no parameters with return value

Tags: swift, function, return-value

I am learning Swift and am writing a basic card game init function where I want to use a function to setup some decks.

Swift keeps complaining that I'm missing an argument in parameter #1, but there aren't any parameters, nor am I wanting any.

`Game` class is as follows

```
class Game
{
    // MARK: ** Private vars **
    private var gameState: GameState?
    private var playerOnTurn: Player?
    private var seedCash:Int?

    // MARK: ** Public vars **
    lazy var players = [Player]()
    var chequesDeck:Deck = Deck()
    var propertiesDeck:Deck = Deck()

    init()
    {
        self.gameState = .Initialize
        self.playerOnTurn = nil  // No player on turn when game is initialized
        self.seedCash = kInitialSeedCash
    }

    func setup(numberOfPlayers:Int)
    {
        // Create decks of properties and cheques
        self.propertiesDeck = Deck.createProperties()
        self.chequesDeck = Deck.createCheques()



    }
}
```

`Deck` class is as follows

```
// Deck of cards
// Two deck types in the game - (1) Properties & (2) Cheques

class Deck
{
    private var cards:[Card] = [] // Empty Array

    // @return: An array of cards
    func createProperties() -> [Card]
    {
        var propertyDeck:[Card] = []


        // TODO: - Needs Local JSON reader
        let prop1 = Card.init(name:"Cardboard box", value:1)
        propertyDeck.append(prop1)

        let prop2 = Card.init(name:"Outhouse", value:2)
        propertyDeck.append(prop2)

        let prop3 = Card.init(name:"Outhouse", value:3)
        propertyDeck.append(prop3)



        return propertyDeck
    }

    // @return: An array of cards
    func createCheques() -> [Card]
    {
        var chequeDeck:[Card] = []

        // create 2 copies of each card, but skip 1s
        for var i:Int = 0; i<=15; i++
        {
            if (i != 1)
            {
                let chequeCard = Card.init(name: "Cheque", value: i * 1000)
                chequeDeck.append(chequeCard)
            }
        }

        return chequeDeck
    }

    func addCard()
    {

    }

    func shuffle()
    {

    }
}
```

`Deck()` is a `class`

```
func setup() {

   var propertiesDeck:Deck = Deck()

   // Create property deck
   self.propertiesDeck = Deck.createProperties()

}

// Deck.createProperties file
// @return: An array of cards

func createProperties() -> [Card]
{
    var propertyDeck:[Card] = []

    let prop1 = Card.init(name:"Penthouse", value:1)
    propertyDeck.append(prop1)

    return propertyDeck
}
```

But Swift keeps complaining that;

> Missing argument for parameter #1 in call

But there aren't any arguments or parameters.

Perhaps I'm doing something wrong/silly?

Comment: Please show the declaration of `Deck` and show us where those function are defined.

Comment: Updated the code to show declartion of Deck class

Comment: The issue I had was many fold (as I am a new Swift developer); the chequesDeck in the game class should be an array of cards, same as propertiesDeck; there were some other issues. But I was able to get the cards to print out into the log which is very good step for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error would generally say that Deck is expecting some constructor parameters. Could you please post your Deck class so I can see if there are any?

Also some more suggestions. You seem to be creating the Deck variable `propertiesDeck`, but then statically accessing `createProperties` by stating `Deck.createProperties()`. Should you not be calling `propertiesDeck.createProperties()`? Also `createProperties` is returning an Array of the Card object, but `propertiesDeck` is a Deck class.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: I've not done much Swift before but its a good comment to review

Answer (score 0):

Since you're accessing your function like this:

```
Deck.createProperties()
```

you probably want a static method instead:

```
static func createProperties() -> [Card] {
    ...
}
```

Which shouldn't give you an error anymore.

Another way to make it work is by calling `createProperties()` on your already defined `Deck` like this (not recommended):

```
self.propertiesDeck = propertiesDeck.createProperties()
```

The reason for the missing parameter comes from the fact that methods take the class instance as their first parameter, so you could actually call it like `Deck.createProperties(propertiesDeck)()`.

I believe you've got some other flaws in your code, I will try to make a better example for you:

```
struct Card {
    let name : String
    let value : Int
}

class Deck {
    var cards : [Card]

    init() {
        cards = [
            Card(name: "Penthouse", value: 1)
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this idea, but now its saying "self.propertiesDeck = Deck.createProperties()" -- Cannot assign value of type [Card] to type Deck; I'm probably overthinking it as the deck is just an array of cards.

Answer (score 0):

Try This,

```
func createProperties() -> [Card]
{
    var propertyDeck:[Card] = []

    let prop1 = Card(name:"Penthouse", value:1)
    propertyDeck.append(prop1)

    return propertyDeck
}
```

If this does not works then show the code for the class Deck and Card.

Answer (score 0):

We can't answer your question without the complete code. We need the code of your Deck class.

But you can try class funcs...

```
public class Cards {

class func createProperties() -> [Card]
{
    var propertyDeck:[Card] = []

    let prop1 = Card.init(name:"Penthouse", value:1)
    propertyDeck.append(prop1)

    return propertyDeck
   }
}
```

You can call the function with:

```
Cards.createProperties()
```